# БД в Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите как решить проблему: есть БД scoreDB, в ней таблица ScoreTable со свойствами Name (string) и Score (int). Хочу отобразить Score, упорядочив по возрастанию: 
  t = from ScoreTable s in scoreDB.ScoreTable
                        orderby s.Score descending
                        select s;

На строке: GameScoreCollection = new ObservableCollection<ScoreTable>(t);

Компилятор возвращает: «The member 'BrainGainWP.ScoreTable.Score' has no supported translation to SQL.»
(GameScoreCollection коллекция, к которой привязываю textBlock)

Если упорядочить по Name все работает:
  t = from ScoreTable s in scoreDB.ScoreTable
                        orderby s.Name descending
                        select s;

код таблицы:
 [Table]
    public class ScoreTable : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {

```
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    private int _Score;
    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            return _Score;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Score!= value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Score");
                _Score= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Score");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Name;

    [Column]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Name");
                _Name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ:

```
private int _Score;
[Column]
public int Score
{
    get
    {
        return _Score;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_Score!= value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Score");
            _Score= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Score");
        }
    }
}
```